# How to get O(log n) space complexity in quicksort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

#### The naive recursive version of quicksort :

```
QUICKSORT(A,p,r)
 if p < r then 
   q=PARTITION(A,p,r)
   QUICKSORT(A,p,q-1)
   QUICKSORT(A,q+1,r)
```

This uses an O(n) extra space

In Cormen ch 7-4 "Stack depth for quick sort" its mentioned that 
- The 2nd recursive call in QUICKSORT is not necessary it can be avoided by iterative control structure.This method is called tail recursion

#### modified version of quicksort :

```
QUICKSORT'(A,p,r)
 while p < r
   q=PARTiTION(A,p,r)
   QUICKSORT'(A,p,q-1)
   p=q-1
```

Space complexity O(log n)

I couldnt understand how the space complexity reduced. 
I dont think its tail recursive

Can anyone pls explain how the space complexity reduced (how the calls use the stack) or any other better way to achieve this.

Comment: What does partition do?

Comment: selects a pivot and arranges the array such that small elements are before it and larger ones are after it and returns the resultant index of the pivot